# Create a view of the 'Recent Log Messages'

Tags: log-messages

I would like to give an admin user (not User 1) permission to see the Recent Log Messages (/admin/reports/dblog), but I only want him to see 'User' logs. As it is a subscription website he could see who has been signing up and cancelling their accounts. But if I was to give them this permission, they will also be able to see all the other log messages, which I do not want them to see.

I have searched for a module that allows permissions by Log Type (access denied/cron/page not found/etc.) , but with no luck. My best idea is if there was a way to create a View of the recent log messages, I could then create a filter to only show User messages.

Is there a module or some hook where I can limit a users access to 'Recent log messages' by 'Type'?

Answer (score 2):

In Drupal 8, you can simply create a view of "Log entries". Just make sure you add a "Type" filter and select "user" as the type.

Then under "Page settings", change the "Access: Permission" to "Role > Administrator". However, if you don't want this user to view other log messages, perhaps that user shouldn't be an administrator? I recommend creating a new role for that type of user.

In Drupal 7, the [Views module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) doesn't allow you to make a view of log entries out-of-the-box, however if you install the [Views Watchdog module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_watchdog), you can do it just like the Drupal 8 method described above.